# JWT in header for login to my node api on Cloud Run (GCP)

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, jwt

I am trying to pass a backend-generated JWT-token through the request header in order to make requests to private routes.
I get 400 from GCP and after having Googled this a bit, there seems to be no other way forward than to use IAP...

Is there straight forward documentation or youtube-video on this?

I use Node, express, mongo, jason-web-token etc.

Thanks![enter image description here][1]

Comment: welcome.. upload your trial code with question and attach error snippet

Comment: Can you share piece of code that you use and where you have the problem?

Comment: No since my code works... I am just getting an error when doing http GET with JWT-token attached in header when user has logged in. GCP doesn't appear to allow this without going via their OAuth-plumbing. My question is if someone knows of a straightforward way of implementing login/access with jwt using Cloud Run...

Answer (score 0):

You can trying using a custom method to authenticate a user by sending a JWT in the authorization header of the HTTP request to your backend API [1].

400 error can mean many things, try using this documentation on troubleshooting JWT validation [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-custom

[2] https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-jwt